# how to parse Column fields of mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a query `("SHOW COLUMNS FROM XYZ_table").` It displays the out like

`Array ( [Field] => policyID [Type] => int(10) [Null] => YES [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ).`

I am only concerned with `PolicyID` with it's type => `int` and `size 10`. How can I ignore other irrelevant data ? 
Here is a code: 
    /* $i has size of this array "$tb_names" */

```
 while ($i!=0){
                $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tb_names[$j] ");
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
        }
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $var = print_r($row,true);
            echo $var."<br>";

        }
    }       
            $i--;
            $j++;


    }
```

Comment: What is the problem having extra fields within array? Or you can simply uset() those from array.

Comment: it's a requirement not to get extra fields , I need to parse them

Comment: You must unset them in PHP, transpose the array in PHP or change your SQL to return only what you want included.

Comment: @pcnate, Alok Patel : Can I parse the reuslt using php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can try this `query`

```
SELECT column_name,character_maximum_length , data_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  'databasename'
AND TABLE_NAME =  'tablename';
```

for specific column

```
SELECT column_name, character_maximum_length, data_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  'databasename'
AND TABLE_NAME =  'tablename'
AND column_name =  'columnname';
```

Without database name

```
SELECT column_name , data_type ,character_maximum_length FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tablename';
```

For `int` length please use `NUMERIC_PRECISION`

```
SELECT column_name , data_type ,NUMERIC_PRECISION FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'tablename';
```

Comment: thnak you soo much it helped me going more close to the solution. 
here is the output: "Array ( [column_name] => policyID [character_maximum_length] => [data_type] => int ) " 
why doesn't it gives me the lenght which I have defined like 10 in this case

Comment: @Raja use `COLUMN_TYPE` instead

Comment: @Raja Please use `NUMERIC_PRECISION` for int type length

Comment: @user1234 : yes it worked somehow. But I need to parse it more.
like 
Col_Name TYPE  Size
PolicyID     INT     10

Comment: @Raja then you shuld use this query `SELECT column_name  AS Col_Name , data_type AS TYPE  ,NUMERIC_PRECISION  AS Size FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'tablename'`

Comment: @user1234 : what if the columns changed ? I mean like a new field is added , but the query will only for this ?

Comment: no  this is a universal query except only Size cause error for that you have to use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM XYZ_table`

Comment: @user1234: I am writing the result in a file like **file_put_contents ($file,$var);**
It copies only last column of a table to file , how can I copy all the columns of a table ? 
please help me out of this.

Comment: @Raja it depends where where you use file_put_contents if you are doing somethimg like this `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $var = print_r($row,true);
           file_put_contents('html.txt',$var); 

        }` its overwrite every time just do this  `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $var.= print_r($row,true);
            
        }
  file_put_contents('html.txt',$var);`

Comment: @user1234 : +1, U are a life saver 
Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify to suit your usecase, but try something along the lines of this:

```
$allowedColumns = array(
    'columna',
    'columnb',
    'columnc',
    'columnd',
);

while( $i!=0 ) {
  $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tb_names[$j] ");

  if( !$result ) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
  }
  if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
      $columns = array();
      foreach( $row as $column ) {
        if( in_array( $column, $allowedColumns ) ) {
          $columns[] = $column;
        }
      }
      $var = print_r($columns,true);
      echo $var."<br>";
    }
  }       
  $i--;
  $j++;
}
```

Comment: I am going to try ur sol

Comment: If it works, mark as answer, if not ask more questions

Comment: I tried ur sol but it ain't working. 
thanks for the effort.